# Describing a simple set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If I were asked to describe set A if:

$(∀x ∈ A)(∃n ∈ N) (2n = x)$

Would I be correct in saying that: for all values of x in A, there exists a natural number that is half of x.

Is there a way I can improve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Every element of $A$ is an *insert term here* natural number.

Comment: Could I say that every element of A is an even natural number?

Comment: Yes, you could :) I believe that was what Brian M. Scott was hinting at.

Comment: @Shaun: Yes, that is, as Juan said, exactly what I had in mind.

Comment: This is because the natural numbers are not closed under division, and so if division by two yields a natural number, then two was a factor, and the number is even. (was going to post a full response, but didn't want to ruin it after the hints).

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** If $x$ is such that half of $x$ is a natural number, then $x$ is a natural number. What is the term describing those natural numbers whose half is a natural number?